# Download a git branch from Dropbox

Tags: git, version-control, dropbox

I am writing an article with LaTeX code from a directory in my Dropbox. I operate git locally in this directory. I have a master branch which is a polished copy of my paper, I make additions and collaborate using branches like [this stack post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6190412/3371413). I am committing locally, but not pushing to an online repo.

When I use another computer, can I get access to the branches via Dropbox.com? I know the master file will appear in the dropbox.com gui, but will I be able to find the branch, since that is what I want to edit. Bare in mind I often use different computers on campus, these are Windows. My personal computer is Linux.

Please do not explain to me about online version control repos or cloud LaTeX options. I know and use both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not going to be a good way to do this via dropbox.com, since you'd have to crack open refs, trees, and blobs to find the right files. (You'd have to replicate git's functionality manually.)

You *could* probably write your own app (using the Dropbox API) to do this.

Comment: Thank you for this. It seems that it makes more sense for LaTeX coding to just work from Dropbox and forget about git. It is not as though you benefit from merge features when writing documents. So it seems justvas efficient to create a new document rather than branching.

Comment: I found the following [stackexchange post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1961515/3371413) to be a useful overview of using Dropbox and git together. Although, bare in mind it is old. The world of cloud computing has changed a lot since 2009.